# Continuous set of eigenvalues-the solution is $u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\widetilde{f}e^{ikx} e^{-k^2t}}dk$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

$$u_t=u_{ xx}, x \in \mathbb{R},t>0  $$
$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$

The solution is of the form $u=X(x)T(t)$.

Firstly we have to solve the problem $X''+ \lambda X=0$:

$\lambda=-k^2$ The solutions from this case go to infinity when $x \rightarrow \infty$

$\lambda=0$ The only solution that I want from this case is $X=c_0$

$\lambda=k^2$ $X(x)=c_1e^{ikx}+c_2e^{-ikx},k>0$. So $X_k=e^{ikx},k \in \mathbb{R} $

The solution of the problem $T'+k^2T=0$ is $T_k(t)=e^{-k^2t}$

So $$u_k(x,t)=X_k T_k=e^{ikx}e^{-k^2t}, k \in \mathbb{R}$$

$$u(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\widetilde{f}(k)X_k T_k}dk$$

So $$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\widetilde{f}(k)e^{ikx} e^{-k^2t}}dk$$

where do we have $\frac{1}{2 \pi}$ from?? From the eigenfunction $X=c_0$??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ddot \smile$

Both forms are equivalent since you can choose $\tilde f$ to contain an extra constant.
It will have been rewritten like that so that it has the form of an inverse fourier transform. For $t=0$ the inverse fourier transform maps exactly to $f$, which is the boundary condition.

Comment: Ahaa!! I got it!!!  And in which cases is the solution of the initial bounadry value problem an integral($u(x,t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\widetilde{f}(k)X_k(x)T_k(t)}dk$) and not a sum($u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{X_n(x)T_n(t)}$)?? When $x \in \mathbb{R}$??

Comment: When the value you are summing over can be any real number from some range. In your case that is $k$ that can take any real value. In your example with $n$ it can supposedly only take positive integer values.

Comment: I understand!!! Thank you very much!!! :-)

Comment: At the problem $X''+ \lambda X=0$ we do the following:
$$$$
$\lambda=-k^2$: The solutions from this case go to infinity when $x \rightarrow \infty$, so we don't want them.
$$$$
$\lambda=0$: The only solution that I want from this case is $X=c_0$
$$$$
$\lambda=k^2$: $X(x)=c_1e^{ikx}+c_2e^{-ikx},k>0$. 
$$$$
$$\text{So } X_k=e^{ikx},k \in \mathbb{R} \text{ that contains all the cases above }.$$
$$$$
That means that we can write $c_0=e^{ikx}$, right? Can the value of $c_0$ be different from $1$??

Comment: Indeed, $c_0=c_1e^{ikx}$ for $k=0$. And yes, the value of $c_0$ can be different from 0, but since all eigenfunctions are determined up to a constant, you can choose $c_0=1$. Btw, isn't $c_1 x + c_2$ also a solution corresponding to $\lambda = 0$?

Comment: Ahaa...At the case $\lambda =0$ we have $X(x)=c_1 x+c_2$, but since we want only solutions that are $< \infty$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$, we want that $c_1=0$,(because $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{c_1 x+c_2}=\infty$) so $X(x)=c_2$...

Comment: Why would we only want solutions that approach zero at infinity?

Comment: We want that the solution is square-integrable.

Comment: But... but... X=1 is not square integrable... and neither is $e^{ikx}$...

Comment: In my notes there is the following:
$$u_t=u_{xx}, x \in \mathbb{R}, t>0$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x), x \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$\text{We consider that the solutions are square integrable. The initial condition will be also square integrable.}$$

Comment: Aha! So you eigenfunctions do not have to be square integrable! You only need that both $f(x)$ and $\widetilde f(x)$ are square integrable, so that the Fourier transform is properly defined.

Comment: Aha...So which is then the general form of the eigenfunctions? We cannot write the eigenfunctions that corresponds to $\lambda =0$, which are $c_1 x+c_2$, or the eigenfunctions that corresponds to $\lambda=-k^2<0$, which are $c_1 e^{kx}+c_2 e^{-kx}$ in the form $e^{ikx}$, can we?

Comment: Well... suppose we pick $u = \frac 1{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb C} g(k)e^{ikx}e^{-k^2t}dk + Cx$. This is the combination of all possible eigenfunctions, including the ones that approach infinity for $x \to \infty$. Then $u$ is the solution of the ODE. We should be able to find a $g(k)$ and $C$ that together satisfy the boundary equation. If we know furthermore that $f(x)$ is a real function that is square integrable (which is _not_ given in your problem statement), we can conclude that $g(k)=\widetilde f(x)$ and $C=0$ due to the Fourier transform theorem.